With Python, fetch in Excel file the value of a cell in a row where a cell in the same row contains the character string from an xml file
I have several xml files with names like :
LLL_ABC0D012_title.xml
LLL_ABC0D013_title.xml
LLL_ABT0G012_title.xml
LLL_ABR0N012_title.xml
There are always 8 characters after the 'LLL_'.
I have an Excel file with over 900 lines that looks like this :



reference
dtp1
dtp2
dtp3




ABC0D012
1_blabla
1_1_blablabla
1_1_1_blablablabla


ABC0D013
1_blabla
1_1_blablabla
1_1_1_blablablabla


ABC0D014
1_blabla
1_1_blablabla
1_1_1_blablablabla


ABT0G012
1_blabla
1_1_blablabla
1_1_1_blablablabla



In my xml files, I have <dtp1>text</dtp1>, <dtp2>text</dtp2>, <dtp3>text</dtp3> tags.
I would like to modify the text of these tags with the text in the cells of the corresponding columns in the table above.
To do this, I'd like my script to do a loop that reads ABC0D012 characters (and then the other) in my xml file title, find the match in the 'reference' column of my Excel file and then look for the corresponding value in 'dtp1', 'dtp2' and 'dtp3'.
I would then like to save these values in a variable to replace the text in my tags.
I'm a beginner in Python. I tried something like :
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

table1 = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Documents/datatypes.xlsx', na_values=['NA'])
table2 = table1.replace('\xa0', ' ',regex=True)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for file in files :
        if file[-4:] == '.xml':
            #print(file)
            xml = ET.parse('LLL_ABC0D012_title.xml')
            root = xml.getroot()
            dtp1_xml = root[8]
            dtp2_xml = root[9]          
            dtp3_xml = root[10]
            num = file[4:12]
            #print(num)
            dtp1_excel = table2['dtp1'].where(table2['reference'] == num)
            dtp1_xml.text = dtp1_excel
            #print(dtp1_xml.text)
            ET.indent(root)
            xml.write("LLL_ABC0D012_title.xml", encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True, method='xml')

But it doesn't work, 'dtp1_excel' does not return the dtp1 value from the table in print function but something like :
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
      ...
931    NaN
932    NaN
933    NaN
934    NaN
935    NaN
Name: dtp1, Length: 936, dtype: object

I have no NaN value in the reference and dtp1 columns and it should only return a single cell value.
What's wrong with my approach ? Could you help me, please ?

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

first check what you have in all table1, next what you have in table2,etc. Maybe you made something to remove values. OR maybe problem is when you read it. OR maybe your num is wrong - e.g. it may have extra spaces which it doesn't display, OR maybe your data has lower case strings but file has upper case name. etc.

maybe problem makes where() - and maybe you should use table2['dtp1', table2['reference'] == num] and later get first element from result - because it will always gives DataFrame or Series  (even if it has one result or zero results)

Why do you import openpyxl, if you use pandas instead to read the Excel row for the job? See also here or you can get the cell values directly by the key, doc

The main problem is .where() which returns all rows
and it puts NaN in rows which didn't match, and it keeps values in rows which matched.
For example
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'X': ['A','B','C'], 
    'Y': ['D','E','F'], 
    'Z': ['G','H','I']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['X'].where(df['Y'] == 'E') gives
0    NaN
1      B
2    NaN
Name: X, dtype: object

but df['X'][df['Y'] == 'E'] gives
1    B
Name: X, dtype: object

But still there is other problem - both give Series and it still needs to use [index] or .iloc[row_number] to get single value
results = df['X'][df['Y'] == 'E']
print(results[1])       # row's index is `1`
print(results.iloc[0])  # row's numer is `0`


Full working example:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'X': ['A','B','C'], 
    'Y': ['D','E','F'], 
    'Z': ['G','H','I']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print('---')
print(df)

print("--- [df['Y'] == 'E'] ---")
results = df['X'][df['Y'] == 'E']
print(results)
print('type:', type(results))

print("--- .where(df['Y'] == 'E') ---")
results = df['X'].where(df['Y'] == 'E')
print(results)
print('type:', type(results))

results = df['X'][df['Y'] == 'E']

print("---")
print('     [1]:', results[1])
print('.iloc[0]:', results.iloc[0])


And you have the same problem - you may need code without .where() and with .iloc[0]
dtp1_excel = table2['dtp1'][table2['reference'] == num].iloc[0]


If you have to compare with more values then you can use
( ... == ... ) & (... == ...)
df['X'][ (df['Y'] == 'E') & (df['Y'] == 'F']) ]

or  .isin()
df['X'][ df['Y'].isin(['E', 'F']) ]


dtp1_excel = table2['dtp1'][ table2['reference'] == num] works but in the end num doesn't always have the same number of characters. Do you know how I can add an 'or' function like dtp1_excel = table2['dtp1'][ table2['reference'] == (num1 or num2 or num3)] ? 'num2' and 'num3' being the other possibilities for the length of 'num'. I've tried that but it doesn't work.
Thank you !

maybe you should use .isin(dataset) or .str.contains(text) to check if column has some part of string. Pandas has many functions.

Code item == (num1 or num2 or num3) never work. It always need item == num1 or item == num2 or item == num3 eventually  item in (num1, num2, num3). But Pandas has for this item.isin([num1, num2, num3])

I added examples in answer (at the end)

.isin([num1, num2, num3]) seems to work ! Thank you once again.

Here is a solution without pandas. I use openpyxl what you also import, but not use. Maybe it makes sense to write the changed XML files into another folder? I have only renamed it here:
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
  
def row_values(row_id, col_w=4):
    val_list = []
    for col in range(col_w):
        val_list.append(ws[row_id][col].value)
    return val_list

def change_xml(filename, data_list):
    root= ET.parse(filename).getroot()
    root[8].text = data_list[1]
    root[9].text = data_list[2]
    root[10].text = data_list[3]
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    ET.indent(root, space='  ')
    tree.write(f"Changed_{data_list[0]}.xml", encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True, method='xml')
    print(f"Changed_{data_list[0]}.xml finished!")


wb = load_workbook("datatypes.xlsx")
ws = wb.active # if you have only one sheet take the active
print("Work sheet title:", ws.title)
#ws = wb['Tabelle1']
       
files = os.listdir(path='./')
for f in files:
    if "LLL" in f: # Because proceeded XML will written in same directory
        for cell in ws['A']: # iterate about the column 'A' of the Excel
           if f.endswith(".xml") and cell.value in f:
               print("Parsed file: ", f)
               change_xml(f, row_values(cell.row))

Because I don't know your xml structure I used this dummy file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <dummy />
  <dummy />
  <dummy />
  <dummy />
  <dummy />
  <dummy />
  <dummy />
  <dummy />
  <dtp1></dtp1>
  <dtp2></dtp2>
  <dtp3></dtp3>
</root>

Output:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root>
  <dummy />
  <dummy />
  <dummy />
  <dummy />
  <dummy />
  <dummy />
  <dummy />
  <dummy />
  <dtp1>1_blabla</dtp1>
  <dtp2>1_1_blablabla</dtp2>
  <dtp3>1_1_1_blablablabla</dtp3>
</root>


Thanks for your help.
I'm a beginner and not used to def, I'm going to use furas' solution to get my work done quickly but I'll try your suggestion for practice and I'll tell you if I succeeded with it.
